# Monitoring / Tuning File Locks in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, tomcat, filesystems, files

I'm running an instance of Apache Tomcat (5.5) on a Windows 2008 platform. I think I'm seeing an issue related to concurrent file access / locking.

When the number of concurrent HTTP threads is increased beyond the default setting (150), I see (using a site monitoring tool) an increasing number of 'unnatural' delays when serving some static content (.js .gif .png etc). By this, I mean that the server takes 20 seconds plus before starting to send or taking 30 seconds to serve a small (2KiB) file.

When Tomcat is busy (serving over 300 threads), CPU usage averages around 50-60% and disk usage is around 10-30mbps.

On a Linux platform, I could list the files open for a given process and tune the number allowed etc etc. Are there any similar tools for Windows?

Alternatively, is there anything else I should be looking into?

Screenshot of site analysis tool:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On a Linux platform, I could list the files open for a given process and tune the number allowed etc etc. Are there any similar tools for Windows?

It's not pretty, but [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) gives you some serious output on file handles.

`\path\to\handle.exe | find /i "filename"`

Comment: I am sure that might be something more elegant and/or builtin into Windows, but rarely do those tools give you a serious, low-level description what is going wrong where. So, I hope this might help you. It helps me a lot.